# Attach road to terrain in a single mesh

Tags: knife-tool

[image]

I have the following terrain and road (extracted from OSM) i want to combine them so i can have 'nice' quads for the road and borders mixing nicely with the terrain; and combine everything in a 'single' mesh'.

I've tried different techniques; knife project, shrink-wrap

But i always end up in a mess of vertices; is there a 'clean' way to end up nicely clean other than spending countless hours adjusting each corners and vertices ?

Thanks

Comment: Why were you not satisfied with the Knife Project tool? Instead of merging the 2 objects, maybe just extrude the vertices of the road?

Comment: Because i want a single mesh !

Comment: there are many ways to build a road on a terrain, I guess the right way will depend on your final goal, for example why do you want it to be one unique mesh, why not a mesh (road) on another one (terrain). Here is a tuto on how to build a road, it's a method among others of course: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJeV8djtlyU

Comment: thanks but again, i want a single mesh; not a mesh on top of the other.

Comment: then create some edges between the vertices and fill the faces with F  ;)   to keep quads you need to use the kind of technics that are explained here: https://topologyguides.com/